# What branch the pipeline executes on gitlab merge request? (source/target/result of the merge)

Tags: git, jenkins, merge, gitlab

We are trying to build a CI with Gitlab / Gitlab+jenkins. The flow we desire to have is:

1. Update (commit + push) in feature branch
2. Merge request from feature branch to master
3. Merge request should check for conflicts & then trigger CI job (GitLab pipeline or Jenkins job)
4. The CI job should operate only on the result of the merge
5. Reviewer should see the status of the CI job and in case of success he can approve the merge in GitLab GUI

Currently we see that the CI job operates on the source branch (to be merged) and not on the merged branch (after conflicts check). Is it possible to execute the CI on the merged branch without pushing to the master in case of CI success? (push only after reviewer approves)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should  be possible to do this manually for you, either in the GitLab Pipeline or in the Jenkins job. Something like

```
branch=`git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2`
git checkout master
git merge $branch
```

You can then run all of your tests on a version that already has been merged into master. I believe that this is what a program like Bors-NG already does, but for GitHub:

https://github.com/bors-ng/bors-ng

You would have to abort if there is a merge conflict and also make sure that both the feature branch and master is on the runner/executor. There are optimizations for git repos where you only clone/fetch part of the history using --depth.

For GitLab, you can also wait for a feature that they are calling "Prospective Merge Pipelines" and you can read more about it here:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/7380

They will run this after a user has pressed merged though, but I think that the end result is still the same; you run tests on the merged results before the actual merge is done.

They have the 22nd of March as the milestone, so it is not very far away! It looks like it will be part of the Enterprise Edition of GitLab though, so it will cost money.

Comment: Thanks! This "prospective merge pipelines" look like the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy if you have a Jenkins file. Specify the branch name you are trying to build every time you push to branch. The Jenkins file will be in the root directory of your project and you can add this code:

```
    stage('Git CheckOut') {
        node  ('your node name') {

           git branch:'your branchname', credentialsId: 'yourGlobalCredentials', url: 'git@url/yourProject.git'
        }
    }
```

When developers are ready to commit code they can change the branch name and that will be the one triggered to build

See [image: approved merge request]

Comment: But trigger will build only the branch. After merge the code contain the combined changes of the branch and the master. I want to check that the merge is ok before committing it to the GIT.

Comment: you can create another job specific for master and it will run only if you feature branch pass the build. So you technically will have two jobs, one that builds from feature branch and changes branches based on what you enter and another job that builds only from master and only if the feqature branch pass the build

Comment: Maybe I can create another job that is dependant on the first but I'm not sure what this shall accomplish. The first job will test the feature branch before the merge, the other will test the master before the merge. No job will test the merged master

Comment: the job for master will be triggered when the merge happens so it will test the merged master (you can use approved merge request , see screen shot in the answer)

Comment: and if the test has failed, the reviewer can disapprove the merge? The master shall keep its state before the merge?

Comment: yes, cuz the build wont be triggered. You can always do some test jobs for testing purposes to see it it works perfectly before attempting on your own jobs. Thats what i do at least